# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS crashes when I click on the launcher icon for a window that is already open

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher, compiz, icons

When I click the launcher icon of a window that is already selected (usually by accident) the screen will freeze for 5-20 seconds and then usually a popup will appear saying that a system error was detected:

```
compiz crashed with SIGSEGV in ScaleScreen::getWindows[abi:cxx11]()
```

Sometimes after this crash when the screen returns to normal the launcher bar is all blacked out with no color as if the screen were frozen, even though it no longer is. This weird behavior will last until I restart.

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution?

Comment: Sounds like this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1497163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and run it
2. Change the settings as follows:

   - **General → OpenGL → Texture Filter** = Fast
   - **Sync To Vblank** = uncheck
   - **Effects &rightarr; Animations** = uncheck
   - **Effects → Fading Windows** = uncheck
3. Reboot

Hope this helps. 
(Sorry for the raw text as writing on phone.)

Comment: This seems to have done it! Will comment back if the issue comes back. Thanks!